# Count all elements with the specific resource ID on the scrollable view

Tags: java, android, scroll, appium, scrollable

Here is the question. How can I count all the elements with the resource ID *body_bubble* on a scrollable view ? 
When I use the `driver.findElements (By.id ("body_bubble")).size()` method, it gets only the elements that are currently in view (visible on the screen).

How can I find all the elements? I know that I can use something like `new UiScrollable(new UiSelector()).scrollIntoView`, but I can't wrap my head around it.

Please help me out.

[image]

Comment: if you do a page source , are you able to see the body_bubble that is not visible ? if not , it is unlikely you are able to get it .

Comment: You are only going to be able to get the count for what is on screen,,,if you want to get the count for everything you are going to need to get the count then scroll to what is off screen get another count

Answer (score 0):

You can try add this is capability:

```
DesiredCapabilities dc = new DesiredCapabilities();
dc.setCapability("autoWebview", true);
```

But note, this will work if your apps is a hybrid type, not a native apps.